# After update trigger information

Tags: postgresql

how can I understand which property or properties were updated and can I understand on which row or get the current row? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the row has a unique identifier, NEW.id will hold the value of that identifier within the trigger function.  In order to see whether the value has been updated you can compare OLD.columnname vs NEW.columnname

You can add

```
 RAISE NOTICE 'id of row: %', NEW.id;
```

to see the values in the output